# Questions about publications in Apple Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

My questions is about the rules of the AppleStore App.

In the application I'm developing I have a UITabBarController. It is created in the AppDelegate and hidden ... Depending on the views is shown and hidden, as desired. It is right to implement that I am developing?

I have released very UIPickerViews but occupies space when I do landscape. I thought I'd create a DropDown as an alternative. Is it correct? There are more alternatives?

Apple can ban the publication of the App to be developed in this way?

Update

In AppDelegate have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

         _tabBarAppDelegate = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    Método para esconder a UITabBarController

        [ShowTabBarController hideTabBar:self.tabBarAppDelegate];
    .....

}
```

Then when you want to show specific views in UITabBarController do :

```
-(void)createTabBarController
{
    NSMutableArray * viewControllers = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ] ;
         UITabBarController * TabBarController = [ [ UITabBarController alloc ] init ] ;

        ViewController * viewController = [ [ ViewController alloc ] initWithNibName : @ " ViewController " bundle: nil ] ;
         UINavigationController * navigationController = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController : viewController ] ;
         [ viewControllers addObject : navigationController ] ;

        ViewController2 viewController2 * = [ [ VisitDetailsViewController alloc ] initWithNibName : @ " ViewController2 " bundle: nil ] ;
         UINavigationController * navigationController2 = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController : ViewController2 ] ;
         [ viewControllers addObject : navigationController2 ] ;

         tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers ;

         self.navigationController.tabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers ;

[ShowTabBarController showTabBar: self.navigationController.tabBarController];


  }
```

Then I will changing the UITabBarController, show and hide. As I is requested by the client.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot parse your question. Can you describe more clearly how your app is set up?

Comment: No, Apple won't ban your app for what you have described.

Comment: Update on my question @AlexWayne.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your design plan, but Apple will not reject you for it. A user might though as it sounds confusing, you can't please everyone with your user experience but you can make it so it isn't confusing and yours as it stands sounds confusing, but it all depends on what the client wants. I have made apps that are confusing before just because the client wants it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can design your app as you wish, Apple won't prevent you from doing this (and will unlikely reject your submission). Another question is whether or not your users will like this (in terms of usability) - but this is not related to review process of Apple.